# Ember.js: Getting value from templates having belongsTo relationship

Tags: ember.js

I'm having problem with getting the value when creating new record having belongsTo relationship.

```
// templates/components/user.hbs
First Name:
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="user.name.first" required="required"}}

Middle Name: 
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="user.name.middle" required="required"}}

Last Name:
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="user.name.last" required="required"}}


// models/user.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.belongsTo('name', {embedded: 'always'}),
});

// models/name.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    first: DS.attr('string'),
    middle: DS.attr('string'),
    last: DS.attr('string')
});


// from my route
model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('user');
}

// create action
var user = this.controller.get('model');
console.log(user.get('name').get('first'));  // it says that the 'name' is null
```

But when I tried to edit the persisted data from the backend, value from 'name' can be accessed.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the limited information available there are a few issues.  `{embedded:'always'}` has been deprecated for some time, and creating a `user` won't automatically create the `name` record.

```
model: function(){
  var store = this.store,
    name = store.createRecord('name'),
    user = store.createRecord('user', {name:name});

  return user;
}
```

You might want to read the transition document https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md